# Обработчик нажатия на клавишу

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Я создал простую программу, которая при клике на клавишу(f3) выполняла   код `if (toggled == false) { if (GetAsyncKeyState(!(VK_F3))) { i = i + 1;}`
Мне нужно, чтобы находились все клавиши, кроме f3. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    int state = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
    if (state == 1 || state == -32767)
        return i;
}
```

Переменная `i` возвращает код клавиши, которая была нажата

**Update** | Проверить нажати ли клавиша F3

```
int getPressedKey()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        int state = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
        if (state == 1 || state == -32767)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool managePressedKey(int keyId)
{
    switch(keyId)
    {
        case VK_F3:
            return true;
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: А можно не возвращая саму клавишу, а просто сказать: это f3 или нет.

Comment: @ПавелВороник поправил